# How can I make VS Code Open Folder/File selector open a text box (like when we remote to another device or WSL) instead of a pop-up window

Tags: visual-studio-code, steam

[image: How to make it behave like this]
How to make it behave like this

[image: Instead of like this]
Instead of like this

This is because I want to launch VS Code in the Steam Deck default UI.

If this question is duplicated, hopefully someone can point me to the answer because, tbh, I don't really know if I ask the right question or not